# Capture windows user credentials in frontend

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, iis, windows-authentication

I have a website that calls an API, the frontend website is controlled by AD, the user will key in their windows credentials to gain access to the website, this website and API are for internal uses only in my organization.

The API accepts all requests and I had to allow all headers to overcome the preflight CORS problem. The way it works is that the website will make an API call, but because these are two different sites on the server, the user that is being passed is the AppPool. I want a way to capture the username the user logged in with to pass it with the request.

I am wondering if I can capture that username from the windows user popup? or something on the Javascript frontend.

Comment: you can just use username = User.Identity.Name; on the backend. Just make an endpoint that returns it to the frontend.

Comment: @pcalkins, I tried this attribute before but it's not working. it is returning a NULL.

Comment: you should make sure "allow anonymous" is off.  Windows Authentication should be the only allowed method at server level.

Comment: @pcalkins, this doesn't work because when setting the API to windows authentication.
The way it is working now is that the browser is making the call to the frontend website, then it is passing the call to the API with the server as the user. (I am not sure if I am making sense) but I am not getting a user in that field in the logs.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have a server-to-server request to the API... if you need the API server to know the user, you'd need to pass that along with the request.

Comment: @pcalkins, that's correct! I am just not sure how to do so.
My front end lives on port 80 for example and my API lives on port 81 of the same server, in my front-end js I call port 81 but then when I look at the logs it says the call came from the server not the browser, is there a way to get IIS to pass on the header from the browser ?

Comment: So browser <-> Server 1.  Server 1 <-> Server 2.  Server 1 has the user info.  So when Server 1 makes a call to Server 2, you need to pass the username to it.  Then server 2 can know it.  I'm still confused as to why you are using two servers here... especially since they are on the same machine, but that's the only way Server 2 can know who the user is.  What you are calling your "front end home", can also be your API's home.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, we don't suggest you capture the username inside the js from the browser's popup.

The windows popup is triggered when the un-auth request send to the server, during that time, no js will be triggered and capturing the user input is not security and may contain risks.

If you want to get the username, one possible way is getting it from the server and send it with response to the client js.

But according to your description, it seems you want to do some action according to the user name.

One possible way is writing a custom middleware to get the user name before the CORS middleware or else.

About how to get it from the middleware, you could refer to below codes:

```
//put this middleware before the middleware which you want to check the user name 
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    // Do work that can write to the Response.
    if (  context.User.Identity != null)
    {
        var username = context.User.Identity.Name;
    }
      await next.Invoke();
// Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.

});
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I tried using this property before and it didn't return anything. I might not be using it right. where would this piece live ? in the Program.cs ?

Comment: Yes, this should add the program.cs

Comment: Well, the problem is that the user is not being passed from the frontend to the API to begin with, so this will always return a NULL in this case.
Is there a way to pass the "LOGON_USER" from the frontend website to the API using IIS settings, please ?

Comment: This is related with how the windows authentication works. When the request come to the server, it must be not auth. The server will return the response to client to let the user login in, browser will show the popup according to the response, unless the user type-in, the server will know the username. So if the user type the username, then the server will get it,